# Is the IIS LogParser still useful on 2008 R2?

Tags: iis-7.5

I have to look at the log files for IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I've been looking around for something that will help me with that. I've come across several websites that talk about IIS LogParser. e.g.:

http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-performance-issues-or-application-errors-using-logparser

However when I look at the system requires here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659 it only looks Windows Server 2000, 2003 and Windows XP. Can I still use LogParser for Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

LogParser is working fine on my Windows 2008R2, just as well as it did on my Windows 2003R2.
In the end it is just an executable that reads textfiles (your logfiles), there is not much to be incompatible.

The only reason that the system requirements do not mention Windows 2008 or newer is probably because it is a very old tool. It has not been updated since April 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, still very useful in 2015.

It installs and works fine on 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2012R2 and 2016.

The only thing to keep in mind is that it is 32bit, which means it wont run if you disable the 32bit subsystem.

You can even xcopy deploy it without running the installer.